# Is codeignitor2 work with xampp 1.2 version

Tags: php

My codeignitor2 application is built with xampp 1.7. When we deploy the same in the production server which is having a xampp version of 1.1.

Actually, after login with one user and logout again by logging with another user id and navigating to the menus. We have seen the earlier (first logged in username instead of second logged in username) logged in user details in the header page.

We will be able to see the session username randomly with both the users some times.

Can u please help me on this to fix.

Comment: Ghostly behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on php version used in xampp and codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Code Igniter should work with XAMPP. See the Code Igniter installation details for detailed instructions.

Comment: Yes, but my product server is having a php version of 4.x.x, where as codeignitor 2.x version supports from 5.1.6.

Comment: php 4.x? php 7.x has been released. Do upgrade your production server to php 5.x

Answer (score 0):

Below are the requirements for Codeigniter

PHP version 5.4 or newer is recommended.

MySQL (5.1+) via the mysql (deprecated), mysqli and pdo drivers

Oracle via the oci8 and pdo drivers

PostgreSQL via the postgre and pdo drivers

MS SQL via the mssql, sqlsrv (version 2005 and above only) and pdo drivers

SQLite via the sqlite (version 2), sqlite3 (version 3) and pdo drivers

CUBRID via the cubrid and pdo drivers

Interbase/Firebird via the ibase and pdo drivers

ODBC via the odbc and pdo drivers (you should know that ODBC is actually an abstraction layer)

So you just need to check your xammp support these